# SQL Datediff Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, datediff

I have a question surrounding a stored procedure I am trying to design.

I have a table with batches of transactions. The current table structure is below. I am trying to write an automated load test where the difference between loading status and loaded status is less than 30 minutes.

If the difference is > 30, it will return fail in a table the stored procedure creates. I am trying to run this with variables as this stored procedure will be triggered by some python code that loads the transactions. There will be roughly 100 batch IDs, so about 200 rows of data the stored procedure needs to dig through.

I am trying to figure out if a loop is the best choice, an if statement, or both. Any help is appreciated.

```
AuditID BatchID  BatchStatus    TimeOccurred
1       TEST_01  Loading        2007-05-10 01:30:00
2       TEST_01  Loaded         2007-05-10 01:59:00
3       TEST_02  Loading        2007-05-10 01:30:00
4       TEST_02  Loaded         2007-05-10 02:00:00
5       TEST_03  Loading        2007-05-10 01:30:00
6       TEST_03  Loaded         2007-05-10 02:05:00
```

Comment: which database you are using

Comment: I've created my own database for this, but I do have AdventureWorks on my PC.

Comment: I was asking about RDBMS you are using. I believe you are using `Sql Server`. Also can you explain this part *it will return fail in a table the SProc creates*

Comment: Correct. I am attempting to figure out if I can store the difference between two batches in a variable, or can do this through the datediff function, an if statement, or a combination of all 3.

Comment: How your result should look like. can you add expected result in table format

Comment: I'm thinking a table would be best with columns such as BatchID, LoadTime, Pass/Fail, but was not sure if that was the best design for this project.

Comment: In `LoadTime` you want to show `Loading` or `Loaded` time

Comment: I would like to have this be a computed column of Loaded - Loading... If > 30, Pass/Fail column will display Fail, if < 30, P/F column will display Pass

Answer (score 2):

Considering that a `BatchID` will have one `Loading` time and one `Loaded` time

Try something like this

```
with cte as
(
select BatchID,
       max(case when BatchStatus ='Loading' then  TimeOccurred END) Loading, -- Min(TimeOccurred)
       max(case when BatchStatus ='Loaded' then  TimeOccurred END) Loaded -- Max(TimeOccurred)
from yourtable 
group by BatchID
),diff as
(
select BatchID,
       datediff(minutes,Loading,Loaded) as Loading_time,
       case when datediff(minutes,Loading,Loaded) > 30 then 'Fail' else 'Pass' End as pass_fail
from cte
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you @VR46! I'm going to look through all of the statements you used. I envisioned it being a lot more simple than this, but I was wrong. I plan on saving this as Stored Procedure and I'm assuming this data will be pushed down further when I trigger the sproc again? Thanks!

Comment: I will suggest you to use this select query as is instead of sproc.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Data table (AuditID int, BatchID  varchar(100), BatchStatus varchar(100), TimeOccured datetime)
insert into @Data (AuditID, BatchID, BatchStatus, TimeOccured) values (1, 'TEST_01', 'Loading', cast('2007-05-10 01:30:00' as datetime))
insert into @Data (AuditID, BatchID, BatchStatus, TimeOccured) values (1, 'TEST_01', 'Loaded', cast('2007-05-10 01:59:00' as datetime))
insert into @Data (AuditID, BatchID, BatchStatus, TimeOccured) values (1, 'TEST_02', 'Loading', cast('2007-05-10 02:00:00' as datetime))
insert into @Data (AuditID, BatchID, BatchStatus, TimeOccured) values (1, 'TEST_02', 'Loaded', cast('2007-05-10 02:35:00' as datetime))

declare @Results table (BatchID  varchar(100), DurationMins int, Success bit)

-- Process each BatchID separately, store results in Results table
declare @BatchID as varchar(100)
Declare @StartTime as datetime
Declare @StopTime as datetime
Declare @MinDiff as int
declare c cursor for 
    select distinct BatchID from @Data
open c
fetch next from c into @BatchID
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin   
    select @StartTime = TimeOccured from @data where BatchID = @BatchID and batchStatus = 'Loading'
    select @StopTime = TimeOccured from @data where BatchID = @BatchID and batchStatus = 'Loaded'
    select @MinDiff = datediff(minute,@StartTime,@StopTime)
    Insert into @Results (BatchID, DurationMins, Success) 
    select @BatchID, @MinDiff, case when @MinDiff > 30 then 0 else 1 end 
    fetch next from c into @BatchID
end
close c
deallocate c
select * from @Results
```